# Python how can I make an int to a string?

Tags: python, string, integer

```
import keyboard
import time

s1 = 1
time.sleep(1)
while s1 < 100:
    keyboard.write(s1)
    s1 = s1 + 1
```

I can't write `s1` because 1 is an int. But if I make it `s1 = "1"` then I can't do `s1 < 100` because `s1` is a string, so I need to write `s1`, but how?

Comment: `keyboard.write(str(s1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the int() or str() function where you need the value to be a string or int without reassigning it.

```
import keyboard
import time

s1=1
time.sleep(1)
while s1<100:
    keyboard.write(str(s1))
    s1=s1+1
```

Comment: Yeah the function is str(). Python doesn't know what string() is.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do here. I also changed the last line as it's simpler like that

```
import keyboard
import time

s1 = 1
time.sleep(1)
while s1 < 100:
    keyboard.write(str(s1))
    s1 += 1
```